# Extract string with grouping in regular expression on terminal

Tags: regex, linux, bash, terminal

I have a text file that conatins some HTML information like this:

```
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDubYJsZ9iM&amp;list=PL5-da3qGB5IBC-MneTc9oBZz0C6kNJ-f2">Lab: K-means Clustering</a> (6:31)</li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u3zvtfqb7w&amp;list=PL5-da3qGB5IBC-MneTc9oBZz0C6kNJ-f2">Lab: Hierarchical Clustering</a> (6:33)</li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk9S3RTAl38&amp;list=PL5-da3qGB5IC8_kWZXDcmLx7_n4RTBkAS">Interview with John Chambers</a> (10:20)</li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l9V1sINzhE&amp;list=PL5-da3qGB5IC8_kWZXDcmLx7_n4RTBkAS">Interview with Bradley Efron</a> (12:08)</li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79tR7BvYE6w&amp;list=PL5-da3qGB5IC8_kWZXDcmLx7_n4RTBkAS">Interview with Jerome Friedman</a> (10:29)</li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEMGOlJxxz0&amp;list=PL5-da3qGB5IC8_kWZXDcmLx7_n4RTBkAS">Interviews with statistics graduate students</a> (7:44)</li>
```

I extract links with `grep -oP "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)" list > links` such that `list` is html file. From another side i need extract the name of each file, i.e. i need another list like this:

```
Lab: K-means Clustering
Lab: Hierarchical Clustering
Interview with John Chambers
Interview with Bradley Efron
Interview with Jerome Friedman
Interviews with statistics graduate students
```

The problem is that i have some tags like `<a href="http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/">An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R</a>`, thus i can't use some pattern with `a` tag. So i must use somethings like pattern grouping that i will able to use some `$1` for first matched pattern, `$2` for second pattern and so on into `https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/[SOME INFORMATION ON URL HERE]/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)`. ***How can i do this on terminal (Bash)?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\">).*(?=</a)" your_file
```

This will print:

```
Lab: K-means Clustering
Lab: Hierarchical Clustering
Interview with John Chambers
Interview with Bradley Efron
Interview with Jerome Friedman
Interviews with statistics graduate students
```

Since there's no easy way to print only captured groups using `grep`, I used  lookahead and lookbehind assertions to ensure only specified parts will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a none-greedy regex like following :

```
>([^<]+?)</a>
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lW6lO4/1)

Or more precise you can use a [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
(?<=>)([^<]+?)(?=</a>)
```

result :

```
Lab: K-means Clustering
Lab: Hierarchical Clustering
Interview with John Chambers
Interview with Bradley Efron
Interview with Jerome Friedman
Interviews with statistics graduate students
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\K` to remove all matched content before what you actually want

```
grep -oP "a href=\"[^>]+>\K[^<]+" file

Lab: K-means Clustering
Lab: Hierarchical Clustering
Interview with John Chambers
Interview with Bradley Efron
Interview with Jerome Friedman
Interviews with statistics graduate students
```

or assuming that `">` doesn't appear anywhere else then

```
grep -oP "\">\K[^<]+" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using portable awk solution:

```
awk -F '<a href[^>]*>|</a>' '{print $2}' file.html
Lab: K-means Clustering
Lab: Hierarchical Clustering
Interview with John Chambers
Interview with Bradley Efron
Interview with Jerome Friedman
Interviews with statistics graduate students
```